# Como traduzir "Python shell" para o português

Tags: tradução-inglês

Estou preparando um roteiro de aula prática para os meus alunos de programação de computadores e estou em dúvida de como traduzir a expressão *Python shell* para o português.

Esta expressão refere-se a um ambiente interativo em que o usuário pode digitar expressões e comandos da linguagem Python para serem avaliados ou executados pelo interpretador da linguagem Python.

Há um *Python shell* que roda em uma página na internet em https://www.python.org/shell/

Algumas alternativas:

- ambiente interativo do Python
- interpretador do Python
- núcleo do Python

Qual é a melhor tradução para esta expressão?

Answer (score 1):

Dado que "Python Shell" e "Python Interpreter" não significam a mesma coisa (ver [1]), me parece que *interpretador do Python* não é apropriado.

Não sou cientista da computação, mas imagino que "núcleo" ("kernel" em inglês) também tem um significado técnico distinto, o que tornaria a expressão *núcleo do Python* inapropriada também.

Dado que, no contexto da computação, "shell" significa "interface de usuário" (ver [2]), uma opção seria utilizar a expressão **interface de usuário do Python** ou, simplesmente, **interface do Python**.

Dado o significado de "interface" em português (ver [3] e [4]), me parece que a última opção destacada acima é equivalente à sua proposta *ambiente interativo do Python*.

[1] [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-Python-Shell-another-way-of-saying-Python-Interpreter-or-is-it-a-different-thing)

[2] [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o))

[3] [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/Interface)

[4] [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/Interface/)

Answer (score 1):

- interface do usuário gráfico de Python
- interpretador ([da] linha de comando) de Python

Shell (in computing)

> In computing, a **shell is a *user interface* for access to an operating
>   system's services**. In general, operating system shells use either a
>   command-line interface (CLI) or graphical user interface (GUI),
>   depending on a computer's role and particular operation. It is named a
>   shell because it is the outermost layer around the operating
>   system.[1](https://wiki.python.org.br/PerguntasFrequentes/SobrePython#O_que_.2BAOk_Python.3F)
>   [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing))

O português correspondente, tirada da página em espanhol da página acima:

shell= intérprete de ordems ou intérprete de comandos

> Existe um site inteiro no Brasil dedicado ao Python. O interpretador
>   de Python e sua extensa biblioteca padrão estão disponíveis na forma
>   de código fonte ou binário para a maioria das plataformas a partir do
>   site, http://www.python.org/, e deve ser distribuídos livremente.

[Python no Brasil](https://wiki.python.org.br/PerguntasFrequentes/SobrePython#O_que_.2BAOk_Python.3F)

Shell:

> Existem vários interpretadores de linha de comando como o Bash, Tcsh,
>   Ksh (para sistemas da famí­lia Unix) e o interpretador do Windows, que
>   não tem nome e é geralmente referenciado pelo seu nome de arquivo:
>   cmd.exe.
>
> **Eles são frequentemente chamados de shell**, por motivos históricos,
>   como se fossem todos iguais, apesar de serem apenas parecidos.
>   [shell em português](http://professores.dcc.ufla.br/~bruno/aulas/linha-comando.html)

Também se usa a palavra shell mesmo em português

núcleo é *kernel* e ambiente interativo é *interactive environment*, nem um dos dois são a tradução de *shell*.

Answer (score 1):

Eu sou informático.

Sempre que alguém fala em *shell*, isso pressupõem uma linha de comando (em vez de um interface gráfico) - em inglês um CLI (*Command Line Interface*).

Assim sendo, creio que a tradução mais próxima seria "**interface de linha de comando do Python**".

Dito isto, na indústria ninguém traduz. Toda a gente usa a palavra *shell*.